# Retornar vários elementos pelo ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Minha duvida é a seguinte, tenho uma tabela no `MySQL` com `id`, `pesquisa` e `data`. Quero dar um `select` nessa tabela no `php` e retornar pelo `ajax` de forma que eu posso inserir cada elemento em uma `td` específica dentro de uma `table`. Como posso fazer isso?

```
<div class="janelaLateral">
    <table id="tdTeste" name="tableConteudoPesquisado" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>id</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Pesquisa Realizada</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


function fImprimir(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "php/listarPesquisaRealizadaBanco.php",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(ret){

                    $("#tdTeste").append(ret);

                }
            });

        }

$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tabelaProva");

$contador = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
    $retorno[$contador] = $row["id"];.$row["pesquisa"].$row["data"];
    $contador++;
}

mysqli_close($conn);

echo json_encode($retorno);
```

Answer (score 2):

Em vez de retornar um `json`, você pode montar no `php` a estrutura em HTML que será inserida na página, dentro do `while`.

Mas antes, sugiro que mude as tags `td` para `th`, dessa forma elas serão interpretadas como títulos de cada coluna.

No arquivo `PHP` chamado pelo `ajax`, você pode fazer assim:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tabelaProva");
$retorno = '';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){ 
   $retorno .= '<tr>' .
                  '<td>' . $row["id"] . '</td>' .
                  '<td>' . $row["pesquisa"] . '</td>' .
                  '<td>' . $row["data"] . '</td>' .
               '</tr>';
}

mysqli_close($conn);

echo $retorno;
```